# Law of Total Expectation question

Tags: statistics

I know that the law of total expectation states that $E[X] = E[E[X|Y=y]]$, but does this law hold for $E[x] = E[E[X|Y \le y]$?

This is not an assignment question, but something I wish I knew to further answer a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the meaning of the outer expectation in $E[E[X|Y\le y]]$?

The expression $E[E[X|Y=y]]$ makes sense in that the conditional expectation can be thought of as a function on Y, i.e. $f(Y=y)=E[X|Y=y]$. Therefore the whole expectation can be viewed as $E[f(Y)]$, which makes sense.

For the latter expectation, to make sense, a similar form is $E[X]=E[g(Y)]$, where $g(Y)\equiv E[X|Y\le y]$ on the event $\{Y\le y\}$, and $g(Y) \equiv E[X|Y>y]$ on the event $\{Y>y\}$. So the expectation goes like $$E[X]=E[g(Y)]=E[X|Y\le y]\cdot P(Y\le y)+E[X|Y> y]\cdot P(Y> y).$$